# How to create two pull request from one fork in github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have forked my repo from master branch and commited few changes and created one pull request .
Now that pull request is not merged .
Meanwhile i need to do some other changes and need to create one more pull request .

So to this this is what i have done .

1. cloned same forked again
2. Create new branch

   git checkout -b TPR-4356-DMS
3. created upstream like this 
   git remote add upstream *http master main url from where i have forked*
4. Then added my changes commited and pushed 
   4.I can see my changes in my branch but when i create pull request i can see my older commits as well .

Please suggest what i am missing here ?
Am i creating upstream correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your second branch was not created on top of the first one. 
You can view this with this command:

`git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

It will show to you a tree of your branches.

Comment: Yes this command shows me all the logs of the other branch ...Is it the correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps

```
git checkout -b TPR-4356-DMS
git remote add upstream yourmaster repo
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push origin TPR-4356-DMS:TPR-4356-DMS
```